# Will an arbitrary read in kernel address space by a kernel thread incur panic?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

As we know in user space, if some virtual address space is not allocated yet but accessed, a page fault will occur.

How about in kernel space? For example, I want to run a kernel thread in Linux to, naively, read each word of the highest 1G address space.

I guess it is OK, i.e. an arbitrary read in kernel address space by a kernel thread will incur no panic. Is it correct? Can anybody detail it? What if read on some empty area?

Answer (score 4):

You can't read a memory address which is not mapped in kernel space, the processor will catch that and generate a fault, which will be reported as an Oops under Linux. See http://www.kerneloops.org/